# Is the following set a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$. Is $B = \{f : [0, 1] → \mathbb{Q}\}$ a subspace?
$$$$
My approach: 1) closed under addition $=>$ let $f$ and $g$ be 2 functions in $B$. Then $f+g:[0,1]→\mathbb{Q}$ since every number is expressed as a ration.

2)Closed under scalar multiplication: let $f∈B$ be a function and '$k$' a scalar: k∈$\mathbb{Q}$. $k*f∈B$ because the product of f and a scalar can be represented as a ratio.

3)Zero Vector: $f(0)→\mathbb{Q}$ exists.

Therefore, in my opinion its a vector space. Now I know that inside the [0,1] interval, we have also irrational numbers, and might change this answer. Any help is appreciated, if Im completely wrong.

Comment: Consider $f\in B$, given by the constant function $f(x)=1$. Why is $\sqrt 2\times f\in B$?

Comment: No, I guess that proves its not a vector space

Comment: Yeah, we're talking about subspaces of a $\Bbb R$-vector space, so the field of scalars is $\Bbb R$ for the purpose of checking whether a subset is closed under scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

Community wiki answer so the question doesn’t remain unanswered:

As discussed in the comments, this is not a subspace because the field of scalars of this vector space is $\mathbb R$ and multiplying a function with only rational values by a real number doesn’t necessarily yield a function with only rational values.